# How can I change the shortcut alt+tab to alt+space?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am trying to change the window switching shortcut, but I cant find it anywhere under keyboard --> shortcuts. What shall I type if I want to add it as a custom shortcut?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It's placed in Window settings not in Keyboard layout

[image]